# Trying to combine two amcharts graphs, but getting "Data fields for series are not properly defined." error

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I am trying to combine two graphs of amcharts into one including the slider. But I am getting the "Data fields for series are not properly defined." error.

These are the separate fiddle code for each graphs.

1. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/k7vduepm/)

[image]

2. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yk3p6ah2/)

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve.

[image]

This is my code:

```
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in

chart.paddingRight = 30;
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "mm:ss";

var colorSetAgent = new am4core.ColorSet();
colorSetAgent.saturation = 0.4;

var colorSetCustomer = new am4core.ColorSet();
colorSetCustomer.saturation = 0.4;

chart.data = [ {
  "category": "Module #1",
  "start": "0",
  "end": "10",
  "color": colorSetAgent.getIndex(2),
  "task": "Agent",
  "value": 4500
}, {
  "category": "Module #1",
  "start": "12",
  "end": "17",
  "color": colorSetCustomer.getIndex(1),
  "task": "Customer",
  "value": 2690
}, {
  "category": "Module #1",
  "start": "25",
  "end": "38",
  "color": colorSetAgent.getIndex(2),
  "task": "Agent",
  "value": 3370
}, {
  "category": "Module #1",
  "start": "42",
  "end": "50",
  "color": colorSetCustomer.getIndex(1),
  "task": "Customer",
  "value": 4510
}];

chart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ss";
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "ss";

var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 70;
dateAxis.baseInterval = { count: 1, timeUnit: "second" };
dateAxis.renderer.tooltipLocation = 0;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

function createSeries(field, name) {
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = field;
    series.dataFields.dateX = "end";
    series.name = name;
    series.tooltipText = "{dateX}: [b]{valueY}[/]";
    series.strokeWidth = 2;

    var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    bullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
    bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
}

createSeries("value", "Series #1");

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series1.columns.template.height = am4core.percent(70);
series1.columns.template.tooltipText = "{task}";

series1.dataFields.openDateX = "start";
series1.dataFields.dateX = "end";
series1.dataFields.categoryY = "category";
series1.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color"; // get color from data
series1.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = "color";
series1.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 1;

chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
```

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hv1d0jo/), but I am getting "**Data fields for series are not properly defined.**" error.  Kindly help me out here.

**UPDATE**: After kelvin's suggestion, I am not getting error any more, but now the both charts are integrated into one chart. Like this:
[image]

Updated [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1t5rsc8f/)

**UPDATE**: Now, after the [demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/QYMREK) link provided by kelvin, my chart looks like this:

[image]

Update [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1t5rsc8f/)

Comment: try adding series.yAxis = valueAxis; to your createSeries()

Comment: @kelvin, thanks for replying. After your suggestion, I am not getting error anymore, but the I am seeing only one chart in which both charts are integrated. Kindly see the updated screenshot of it.

Comment: @kelvin, if possible, can you look into the updated jsfiddle link?

Comment: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/QYMREK check out this

Comment: @kelvin, I have gone through the link and now I am able to show two separate chart, perfectly, as I wanted. There are few things are not perfect, in case of data, but I'll handle that later. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding series.yAxis = valueAxis; to your createSeries()

Adding this for future refs.

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

var data = [];
var price = 100;
var quantity = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    price += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 100);
    quantity += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 1000);
    data.push({ date: new Date(2000, 1, i), price: price, quantity: quantity });
}

var interfaceColors = new am4core.InterfaceColorSet();

chart.data = data;
// the following line makes value axes to be arranged vertically.
chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = "vertical";




// uncomment this line if you want to change order of axes
//chart.bottomAxesContainer.reverseOrder = true;

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 8;
dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.1;
//dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = false;
dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.2;

chart.leftAxesContainer.pixelPerfect = true;
dateAxis.pixelPerfect = true;
dateAxis.renderer.pixelPerfect = true;
dateAxis.renderer.gridContainer.layout = "absolute";

// these two lines makes the axis to be initially zoomed-in
//dateAxis.start = 0.7;
//dateAxis.keepSelection = true;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
valueAxis.zIndex = 1;
valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
// height of axis
valueAxis.height = am4core.percent(60);
valueAxis.renderer.inside = true;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "bottom";
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.padding(2,2,2,2);
//valueAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.95;
valueAxis.renderer.fontSize = "0.8em"

// uncomment these lines to fill plot area of this axis with some color
valueAxis.renderer.gridContainer.background.fill = interfaceColors.getFor("alternativeBackground");
valueAxis.renderer.gridContainer.background.fillOpacity = 0.05;


var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "price";
series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
series.name = "Series 1";




var valueAxis2 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis2.tooltip.disabled = true;



// height of axis
valueAxis2.height = am4core.percent(40);
valueAxis2.zIndex = 3
// this makes gap between panels
valueAxis2.marginTop = 30;
valueAxis2.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
valueAxis2.renderer.inside = true;
valueAxis2.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "bottom";
valueAxis2.renderer.labels.template.padding(2,2,2,2);
//valueAxis2.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.95;
valueAxis2.renderer.fontSize = "0.8em"

// uncomment these lines to fill plot area of this axis with some color
valueAxis2.renderer.gridContainer.background.fill = interfaceColors.getFor("alternativeBackground");
valueAxis2.renderer.gridContainer.background.fillOpacity = 0.05;

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series2.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(50);
series2.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series2.dataFields.valueY = "quantity";
series2.yAxis = valueAxis2;
series2.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
series2.name = "Series 2";

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

var scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
scrollbarX.series.push(series);
scrollbarX.marginBottom = 20;
chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;

let rectangle = chart.plotContainer.createChild(am4core.Rectangle)
rectangle.fillOpacity = 1;
rectangle.width = am4core.percent(100);
rectangle.fill = am4core.color("#ffffff")
rectangle.isMeasured = false;
rectangle.height = 29;
rectangle.zIndex = 1000;

valueAxis2.events.on("positionchanged", function(){
  rectangle.y = valueAxis2.pixelY - rectangle.pixelHeight - 1;
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Source :https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/QYMREK